# dc motor calculation

Tags: voltage, dc-motor, torque, back-emf

I'm having trouble with this problem. Suppose the machine was at rest, and a weight of 5 kg was suspended from a horizontal bar of length 80 cm attached to the shaft.
What current must be applied to the armature to keep the arm horizontal?
I think I need an expression of the torsions equal to 0. but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: A 5kg weight applies a force of about 50N, so there's a torque of 40Nm on the shaft. You will need a current of 40/kt through the motor, where kt is the torque constant expressed in Nm/A.  Somewhere in the rest of the problem will be the information to help you evaluate kt, perhaps the spec of the motor, perhaps a torque measurement at some other current, perhaps the field strength and the effective number of turns on the motor armature, perhaps the speed constant kv and some power measurements, perhaps moment of inertia+a graph of current versus time, something.

Comment: I have kt=.7Vs/rad

Comment: Excellent, so you have the speed constant in Vs/rad. Now just equate power, power in = power out, torque x speed = volts x amps (keep torque and speed very carefully in SI units, Nm and rad/s), so from the speed constant you can compute the torque constant, and then you can solve for torque and current.